# iOS Game Center - Quit turn-based games for previous version of app

Tags: iphone, ios, multiplayer, turn-based, game-center

I have a game on the iOS App Store that uses Game Center for turn-based multiplayer (GKTurnBasedMatch). I recently updated the app with a new game mode and I had to change the network protocol for that to happen. As a result I marked my new version as incompatible with the old one. That is, you cannot see the old games within the new app and you cannot initiate a game with someone with the old version of the app. This works as expected. However:

**The old games remain active after updating. There seems to be no way to quit them.** What is worse is that **they still count to the maximum number of games you can start**. I have been contacted by players that can only start 1-3 games without hitting the roof.

Have anyone experienced this before? Is there any way to quit the games?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm specifically looking for something to tell my players. E.g., "Do x in Game Center to remove the games", or, "There is a time-out after x days where the games will terminate automatically".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand... What "quit" functionality exists in the game as it is? Do users have a quit option that is now broken? Did you expect the data files (storing the active games) to be removed when the app updated?

Comment: Creating/quitting/resuming games are all handled by Apples code in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController. This view will not display games from the previous version, but they are still active and takes up slots.

Comment: `The old games remain active after updating. There seems to be no way to quit them.` Can you provide some more context that describes what this actually means?

Comment: They are still active on the Game Center server but they are not visible in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact [Apple tech support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/). Submit a TSI and request that they terminate the active games.

Additionally you can see if your question has been answered already, or ask your question on the [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/).